# ASP.NET master page hyperlink controls not working

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, master-pages

I am new to ASP.NET (and web development in general).
For some reason, in my ASP.NET master page, the hyperlink web controls are not working.

I want them as web controls so I can change the "Login" hyperlink text to "Log out" (as well as its navigateURL) if the user session is currently logged in.

Could anyone find the problem?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 468px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper" runat="server">
        <div id="header" class="container" runat="server">
            <table style="width: 100%; height: 128px;" runat="server">
                <tr>
                    <td class="style1" runat="server">
                        WEBLINK
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">About</asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" 
                            NavigateUrl="~/InterestPages/InterestNews.aspx">Interests</asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server">Blogs</asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="loginLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" 
                            ViewStateMode="Enabled">Login</asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is my C# master page code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    private void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["LoggedIn"] != null && (bool)Session["LoggedIn"] == true)
        {
            MasterPageFile = "~/LoggedIn.master";
        }
        else
        {
            MasterPageFile = "~/Site.master";
        }
    } 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["LoggedIn"] != null && (bool)Session["LoggedIn"] == true)
        {
            loginLink.Text = "Log out";
            loginLink.NavigateUrl = "";
        }
        else
        {
            loginLink.Enabled = true;
            loginLink.Text = "Login";
            loginLink.NavigateUrl = "~/Account/Login.aspx";
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: try  <a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("LogOut.aspx") %>"><strong>Log Out</strong> </a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just replace your login menu link with the asp LoginView control?
You can add an Anonymous template with your login link to point to your login page, and
a LoggedIn template with your logout link by adding the LoginStatus.
It let's you provide a welcome to the logged user.
Oh, and it also let's you get rid of all that preinit stuff and session tracking.

You can use the user identity isAuthenticated to determine if that session is logged in.

And if you want to use a different master page for your login page ... you can just create one for your login page or point it to another master page.

I also don't think your pre-init is firing.

Comment: I'll try that approach out and see how it goes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have empty NavigateUrl  when session is not null . So please change this line `loginLink.NavigateUrl = "#";`

try this code

```
if (Session["LoggedIn"] != null && (bool)Session["LoggedIn"] == true)
        {
            loginLink.Text = "Log out";
           loginLink.NavigateUrl = "#";
        }
else
        {
            loginLink.Enabled = true;
            loginLink.Text = "Login";
            loginLink.NavigateUrl = "~/Account/Login.aspx";
        }
```